# Can I save a query set for django manytomayfield

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model suppose

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class B(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

Now can I say if I have to save these models I can use

```
users = A.objects.all()
```

and suppose I have a data for to store as

```
b = B(city="XYZ", user=users).save()
```

that is can I use directly the complete query set to store the manytomany field data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a many-to-many field when you instantiate a model, in any case.

After the model is saved, though, you can do:

```
b.users.add(*users)
```

Comment: that means I can do like b = B(city="XYZ").save(commit=False) and then use this solution

Comment: Er, no. Firstly, `commit=False` is for forms, not models.  Secondly, as I said above, you have to actually save it to the database before you can add m2m data.